# Cómo puedo aplicar el regex a un campo dirección de residencia?

Tags: laravel-8

cómo se encuentran el día de hoy?

Estoy aprendiendo laravel y estoy teniendo un inconveniente con la validación de un campo (dirección de residencia). Lo que deseo hacer es que sólo reciba letras, números, raya(-), punto(.) y numeral(#).

El código lo tengo así: `'nombre' => 'required|string|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9.#-]+$/'`

**Nota:** estoy usando la palabra reservada de regex de laravel

Comment: @Hector ¿Y cuál es el problema? ¿En qué falla? ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta agregando más detalles y ejemplos de texto con los que debería coincidir? Me imagino que al ser una dirección también te interesa permitir espacios

Comment: @Pollo, gracias por la corrección, ya eliminé el comentario.